# Set dynamic domain name in Url of emain - DJANGO

Tags: python, django

I am buiding a web app using Django. When I use reset password, it sends an email to user. That url in the email has static domain - the domain that i set in admin/site. But I want that domain in the url of email changing dynamically. For example: if I run server on port 8000, url is http://localhost:8000/...., when I run on port 8001, url is http://localhost:8001/..... Can anyone give me a solution ?. I used get_curent_site(request), but It doesn't work.

Comment: looks like you have to save your url to a variable, and pass the variable to the URL in the email you want to send...

Answer (score 1):

E.g.

> python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

listens on every interface on port 8000.

It doesn't matter whether you access the webserver with the IP or the hostname. I guess you are still in your own LAN.
If you really want to access the server from outside, you also have to configure your router to forward port e.g. 8000 to your server.

Check your firewall on your server whether incoming connections to the port in use are allowed!

Assuming you can access your Apache server from the outside successfully, you can also try this:

Stop the Apache server, so that port 80 is free.
Start the development server with sudo python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get the full uri with domain. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri